# Open links in current tab of JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

The code from official website seems only binds click event to links at first load. When a new page is loaded, all links seem to be unbinded so any further clicks will leave the page.

```
$('#example').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

How to bind click events to links in every new page loaded into current tab?

Answer (score 3):

try [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

```
    $('a', ui.panel).live('click', function() {
        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: worked flawlessly for me, thanks for the question and the answer.